# UIBarButtonItem setTintColor white but when run in a real phone it change to gray

Tags: ios, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

I set the `UIBarButtonItem` `tintColor` to white, It is white appearance in storyboard and the simulator，But when run in a  real phone it comes to gray! Why are so strange?

In real phone:
[image]

Simulator:
[image]

Also When set a `UIBarButtonItem` image has the same problem

In real phone:

[image]

In Simulator:

[image]

Comment: You use same iOS version?

Comment: yes, the same version as iOS 8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and next approach helped me:

1. Go to the iPhone Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Increase Contrast
2. Darken Colors turn off;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line for navigation button

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```